# Is my understanding of the Central Limit Theorem correct?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Have I got this correct -

Say we have a population. We take a random sample of size $n$ from this population. I.e. we form a sample $S$ based on random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ taken from this population. So the sample $S$ is a set consisting of of these random variables, and hence the mean of the sample $\overline X$ will be a function of these random variables.

The distribution of $\overline X$ will be approximately normal. And if we keep taking samples infinitely, and standardizing $\overline X$ by taking $$h(x) = \frac{\overline X - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$$ the limiting distribution of $h(x)$ will be $N(0, 1)$.

Is my understanding correct here?

Comment: The following is probably neater notation. Let $h(x) = \sqrt{n} \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$. Then the limiting distribution of $h(\overline X)$ is $N(0, 1)$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're essentially correct. There's one important thing you've implied by saying "random" but haven't stated explicitly, which is that the random variables must be *independent*. (It is often stated that the variables must be identically distributed as well as independent, but this can be relaxed somewhat.)

Also, there's a caveat that the mean and variance (or second moment $E(X^2)$) must exist / be finite. (See e.g. the [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) for a problematic distribution.)